# Timeout inside "beforeEach" not being respected by test

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js

I know that for testing API endpoints, the xhtml request should be mocked, but for now I want to test it with the real API.

**What I want to do:**

Open a page, click the connect button and then wait for a maximum of 10 seconds for a certain element's `innertext` to change to "Connected".

Here's my simple test code:

```
    const assert = require('assert');
    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    const By = webdriver.By;
    const until = webdriver.until;
    const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
    const test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
    const mochaTimeOut = 25000;


    test.beforeEach(function() {
      this.timeout(mochaTimeOut);
      driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();
      driver.get('http://127.0.0.1/dist/popup.html');
    });

    test.afterEach(function() {
      driver.quit();
    });

    test.describe('Connect functionality', function() {
      test.it('Try to connect', function(done) {
        // this.timeout(22222); // only works if I uncomment this line
        driver.findElement(By.id('connect')).click().then(function (el) {
            driver.findElement(By.id('state')).then(function (stateEl) {
              driver.wait(until.elementTextContains(stateEl, 'Connected'), 10000);
            })
          }).then(done);
      });
    });
```

If I run this test as it is, I get this error:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

But if I uncomment this line, it works:

```
// this.timeout(22222);
```

I don't really like using timeouts, but I don't see other way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to `timeout` are hierarchical. The problem is that your `beforeEach` has no children. You need to set your timeout globally or you could duplicate it inside the `test.describe` call:

```
test.describe('Connect functionality', function() {
  this.timeout(mochaTimeout);
```

This way it will apply to all the tests inside the `test.describe` block.